# Getting id of image button inside gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to get the id of an image button inside of a gridview that is inside an updatepanel.

```
 $("<%# gvLineItems.ClientID %> tr img[id*='ibDelete']").click(function() {
                                                                alert('hi');
                                                                $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                                                                    $(this).remove();
                                                                });       
                                                         });
```

What I want to do is upon clicking a delete button I want to fade the row out of my grid view then completly remove it.

This is not workign but is not throwing any errors.
I have this inside of $(document).ready()

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're grabbing the client id of the control incorrectly. Try this:

```
$("#" + "<%# gvLineItems.ClientID %> tr").find('#ibDelete').click(...)
```

EDIT:

Per our discussion in chat:

```
$(".TempName").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(10000, function() { 
        $(this).remove(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Now when I run my site I get an error : The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Sry, typo. It should be `<%#` not `<%=`. The important thing is that you prepend the hash to the ID.

Comment: Still not executing the jquery, no script errors, but it does not do the alert or the fade effect.

Comment: It sounds like you have a selector problem. Try out my edit above. Even better, assign the image a class and select by class. If you can post the markup that's rendered, I could write the selector for you.

Comment: @JamesHill let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2336/discussion-between-ojm86o-and-james-hill)

Comment: I had to go today, can I ping you tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a small typo - remove the # from the asp script snippet as follows

```
$("#" + "<%= gvLineItems.ClientID %> tr img[id*='ibDelete']")
```

You cannot bind an event to an element with the same id, even if it is in a different container.

```
$("<%# gvLineItems.ClientID %> tr img[id*='ibDelete']")
```

id="ibDelete" is a NO-NO.

Just change this to a class definition on the image and call it using 'img[class=lbDelete]'.

Finally, when you are usng inline scripting anywhere in the page, the operator '#' or '=' mean different things in terms of when and how they are executed. But like you pointed out, you will get an error when a client side script tries to use inline script tag content which is generated on the fly.

To resolve this, simple put the entire script tag into a server side control as such:

```
<div runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        .....
    </script>
</div>
```

Lemme know if you need anymore help, Cheers!

Comment: no your first issue will not work, it causes the following to be thrown The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: hey, no problem, that error is coming because you have put the script as-is in the page. to fix it, just put the whole script tag inside a DIV which is a server side control. that way should work just fine.